# Is this the valid contact header and can you explain the parameters

Tags: sip, request-headers

I am new to sipp and network concepts i got a contact header

```
"Fin Tax" <sip:b2fdfc58-b7f2-a482-572c-8dbc1aae24@10.195.1.41:5060>;+
"ip.instance="urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-34db8dc64>";+
u.sip!devicename="ATA34DBFD8DC64"4DBFD18DC64";+u.sip!model.cc.co.com="681"
```

Can you explain this contact paramerter i know the first part uri but what are next parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter is **+sip.instance** (the double quote after + in the example above is a typo for sure), which is defined by IETF, it can be found in SIP Outbound (RFC5626) and GRUU (RFC5627):

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5626
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5627

Its purpose is to identify uniquely a device, independent of contact address (which can change in case of roaming around wifi hotspots or 4G/5G networks) or multiple connections, but contact addresses can also overlap when devices are located in private networks using same IP range.

Usually its value is built using a UUID (universally unique identifier), which should reduce the risk of duplicate values for users with multiple devices. Its uniqueness allows SIP Registrar Server to identify what contact record to update or remove when processing REGISTER requests from the same device.

The next two parameters prefixed with **+u.sip!** seem to be custom parameters set by the sending SIP UA. They look like specific to some CISCO equipment, probably a gateway. In general, SIP specifications tell that custom parameters can be ignored by receiving UA, if it does not know how to interpret them.